# How can I get the Total Memory and the Free Memory from OSX so that I can use it from a PHP program?

Tags: php, macos

I'm working on a system that was developed for linux and that needs the Total Memory of the machine and the Free Memory.

For that, the system used the /proc/ folder of linux to get that data, but mac doesn't have that folder.

Two days ago I got bored of running a virtual machine on my computer only to be able to test and started making the program compatible with mac.

Because of that I started evaluating different methods, but none worked.

The most popular answers that you can see on internet if you search for this problem are the following:

- free (-bash: free: command not found // It doesn't exist in mac).
- Top (I was able to look at the info in the console, but I wasn't able to retrieve it from the code).

But because of the reasons I added between the parenthesis, they are not useful.

How can I get the Total Memory and the Free Memory on a mac computer so that I can use it from a program?

---

NOTE: I am working on php. If you have a php solution, it will work, but I prefer a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [are bunch of answers from apple.stackexchange.com from an exact duplicate of this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems), wasn't hard to find from a simple Google search.

The Python solution that uses `ps` and `vmstat` could easily be re-written directly in PHP in just about the same amount of lines of code.

There are many solutions included, all the command line ones have outputs that can be parsed.

All the Python and Ruby solutions pretty much explain in plain simple code how to use `sysctl` and parse it's output to get the free memory. Most of them are single functions or even one liners.

Here is a [list of all the Unix command line tools that ship with OSX](http://ss64.com/osx/), you might find [something more platform specific](https://superuser.com/questions/197059/mac-os-x-sysctl-get-total-and-free-memory-size), but the `free` work alike scripts in the above link would be more platform agnostic.

Comment: I had already seen that page. There is a python method (I don't use python). a top solution (I cant get the output), two ruby scripts (I don't know ruby). last solution doesn't work on lynux, only on mac. It works, but I wanted to see if there was a gneral solution to linux and mac.

Comment: you don't need to use python, just use the output of that script, it outputs text that could easily be parsed by just about anything else. you could even re-write what it is doing in PHP, it is trivially simple what it is doing.

Comment: `top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem:/ {print $10}'` simple as it gets. `top` and `awk` are pretty much bone stock standard Unix tools

Comment: top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem:/ {print $10}' works on mac, but in linux I get a problem with the -l option (At least on my build). I'll try to re-write what it is doing in PHP. That way I'll also start learning python a little bit.